# MongoDB query documents having a latest value of a field and keeping other fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Suppose that I have this schema document in mongo:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("asd9024380s"),
    "timestamp" : 1581407619976,
    "value" : 5,
    "typeId" : ObjectId("lkjdsa08934"),
    "unitId" : ObjectId("ce234890")
}
```

First of all I want to consider only the documents having, for example, `abc` as `unitId`. Among them, for each `typeId` I want retrieve only the latest one (the one having the highest `timestamp`).

Suppose the collection is like:

| _id | timestamp | value | typeId | unitId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 3 | "ff" | "abc" |
| 2 | 17 | 2 | "ff" | "fff" |
| 3 | 18 | 3 | "gg" | "abc" |
| 4 | 21 | 5 | "gg" | "fff" |
| 5 | 15 | 4 | "ff" | "abc" |
| 6 | 24 | 2 | "gg" | "abc" |

I would like to get:

| _id | timestamp | value | typeId | unitId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 3 | "ff" | "abc" |
| 6 | 24 | 2 | "gg" | "abc" |

I was using this query:

```
db.observations.aggregate(
   [
     { $match: {"unitId": "abc",
     { $sort: { "typeId": 1, "timestamp": 1 } },
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: "$typeId",
           lastSalesDate: { $last: "$timestamp" }
         }
     }
])
```

But this retrieves only the fields of `timestamp` and `typeId` whereas I am also interested in the others, especially `value` and being an aggregation I am not sure I modify it to include `value` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get full object using `$$ROOT`,

```
{
  latestRecord: { $last: "$$ROOT" }
}
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pyVoaYKJrzE)

You can get required fields specifying the name of the field,

```
{
  latestRecord: { 
    $last: {
       _id: "$_id",
       timestamp: "$timestamp",
       alue: "$value"
    } 
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/745zJWoF-tj)

Answer (score 0):

Try using "projection". For example:

```
db.observations.aggregate(
   [
     { $project: { "typeId": 1, "timestamp": 1, "value": 1 } },
     { $match: {"unitId": "abc"}},
     { $sort: { "typeId": 1, "timestamp": 1 } },
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: "$typeId",
           lastSalesDate: { $last: "$timestamp" }
         }
     }
])
```